# How to change the original request url to routed url in spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

Application.yml file is as below:

```
cloud:
  gateway:
     routes:
       - id: first-service
         uri: http://somehost:8060
         predicates: 
           -Path = /first-service/**
         filters: 
           -RewritePath=/first-service/(?<segment>/?.*),$\{segment}
```

I am calling the get request from browser with some query params as below:

http://localhost:8080/first-service/?date=2020-12-03&id=323&op_mode=dev

The request is getting redirected to http://somehost:6060/?date=2020-12-03&id=323&op_mode=dev  but that doesnot get reflected in the original url that I triggered in browser.

I want the redirected hostname and port to reflect in the browser request url

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Not sure for correct config in yaml, I prefer java config. Did you try
```-RewritePath=/first-service/(?<segment>/?.*),/first-service/$\{segment}```

Comment: That only removes the 'first-service' part not the  host and port